# ViewModel PropertyChangedEventHandler null When Invoked From MessageCenter Subscription

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my `ContentPage` I subscribe with the `MessageCenter` waiting on an event to occur. When I receive that message I need to update my `ViewModel` that has a `BindingContext` to my `ContentPage`, like so:

## Page

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        Model = new ViewModel();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application>(Application.Current, "MyMessage", (sender) =>
        {
            Model.Activated = true;
        });

        // ...

        Title = "My Page";
        Content = stackLayout;
        BindingContext = Model;
    }

    public ViewModel Model { get; private set; }
}
```

## View Model

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _activated;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool Activated
    {
        get { return _activated; }
        set
        {
            _activated = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Activated)));
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to set `Model.Activated = true;` from the message subscription, I get a null reference exception on the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` (`PropertyChanged`) in my `ViewModel` here:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Activated)));
```

I assume this is because the message center is running on a background thread or something.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Any difference move the bindingcontext before message.sub function

Comment: Wow, that was it! Post as the answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the bindingcontext assignment before Messagecenter function